# Passing flag variable to go program causing strange output

Tags: parsing, command-line, parameters, go

```
sergiotapia at Macbook-Air in ~/Work/go/src/github.com/sergiotapia/gophers on master [!]
$ go build && go install && gophers -github_url=https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=location%3A%22San+Fransisco%22+location%3ACA+followers%3A%3E100&type=Users&ref=advsearch&l=
[1] 51873
[2] 51874
[3] 51875
[4] 51877
[2]   Done                    q=location%3A%22San+Fransisco%22+location%3ACA+followers%3A%3E100
[3]   Done                    type=Users
[4]+  Done                    ref=advsearch
```

---

I'm trying to use the long github url as a parameter in my code for [Gophers](https://github.com/sergiotapia/gophers). It works fine for all other url types such as organisations or stargazers. However when I try to use the search results page I get the strange output above.

https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=location%3A%22San+Fransisco%22+location%3ACA+followers%3A%3E100&type=Users&ref=advsearch&l=

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "log"
    "strings"

    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
)

type user struct {
    name     string
    email    string
    url      string
    username string
}

func main() {
    url := flag.String("github_url", "", "github url you want to scrape")
    flag.Parse()
    githubURL := *url
    doc, err := goquery.NewDocument(githubURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    if strings.Contains(githubURL, "/orgs/") {
        scrapeOrganization(doc, githubURL)
    } else if strings.Contains(githubURL, "/search?") {
        scrapeSearch(doc, githubURL)
    } else if strings.Contains(githubURL, "/stargazers") {
        scrapeStarGazers(doc, githubURL)
    } else {
        scrapeProfile(doc)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a bash command line (or whatever the mac uses). `&` and `?` are shell metacharacters that you MUST escape. The shell has absolutely no idea what a URL is, nor should it ever have to.

```
go 'http://....'
   ^-----------^
```

Adding quotes will prevent the shell from parsing the metacharacters. The alternative is to manually escape each and ever metachar yourself:

```
go http://example.com/script.php\?foo=bar\&baz=qux
                                ^--------^
```

which quickly gets tedious, and error prone.